# Selenium IDE File menu entries do nothing

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

How do I fix the File menu in Selenium IDE on Firefox 20? As [reported](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5461) elsewhere, none of the commands in that menu do anything* after upgrading Firefox from the previous version. So far I've tried restarting the browser, resetting the Selenium options, and disabling the Firebug extension, which a colleague reported had fixed similar issues in the past.

* If I click File → New Test Case and then File → Recent Test Suites → any test suite, it asks "Would you like to save the test suite?" even though it didn't show the test case before and doesn't show the test suite afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Selenium doesn't check the compatibility when updating Firefox - Uninstalling the extension and [installing the latest version](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) turned out to be sufficient to fix this.